# Why unit tests are still not mocked as when debugging its moving to data access layes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

```
var ClosedLoopTrxSyncDAL = new Mock<ITrxSyncDAL<DeviceTrxSyncTracking>>();
 Mock<IOptions<AppSettings>> appSettings = new Mock<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
 var dt = new DataTable();

 var isValid = true;
DeviceTrxSyncTracking transactionItems = new DeviceTrxSyncTracking()
List<ClosedLoopTrxItem> ClosedLoopTrxList = new List<ClosedLoopTrxItem>();   
ClosedLoopTrxSyncDAL.Setup(post => post.InsertTransaction(dt, transactionItems)).Returns(isValid);
var controller = new ClosedLoopSyncController(appSettings.Object);
SyncDataAnchor result = controller.ClosedLoopSyncService(ClosedLoopTrxList);
```

here the debugger moves to data access layer even after mocking it and returning my own object.  expected: when i debug the test, from business layer it should not move to data access layer rather it should return a ready made object

Comment: You can mock the desired values via appSettings object. You should check https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell mocked object what to return when something tries to access the settings. For example, if your `AppSettings` class looks like this:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

In your test code above you can create an `AppSettings` object and populate the values you want. E.G.:

```
 Mock<IOptions<AppSettings>> appSettings = new Mock<IOptions<AppSettings>>();

 var testAppSettings = new AppSettings { MyValue = "This is a test" };
 appSettings.SetupGet(a => a.Value).Returns(testAppSettings);
```

Now, when your controller class reads the `MyValue` property it will get the string `"This is a test"`.

Comment: The above solution works fine. But still here the debugger moves to DAL which should isn't the expected as I have mocked as below and it will return isValid object                       
ClosedLoopTrxSyncDAL.Setup(post => post.InsertTransaction(dt, transactionItems)).Returns(isValid);

Comment: I don't see where the `ClosedLookTrxSyncDAL` is passed to the controller (or any other class) to use. Just adding a `Setup` to the mock isn't enough. You need to pass that mock to the class that is using it. Are you injecting it elsewhere? It's hard to tell with only the unit test code. Can you edit your question and add the code where the DAL object is being passed in and called?